# What is unit of Forms Authentication timeout in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timeout

Is it in minutes? 
It is in "2880", but  this timeout is too short. Doesn't seem to be in minutes...

```
   <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
   </authentication>
```

Comment: It is minutes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: How long do you think it is taking if it isn't taking 2880 minutes to time out?

Comment: Thanks! 
Because I was testing in another web.config, then don't saw the effect in timeout...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
```

FormAuthentication timeout is in ***minutes***. 2880 means 48 hours.

Default is 30 minutes if you do not explicitly set it.

Comment: Any event in ASP.NET (MVC) when the timeout (cookie auth) expires ?